# What does "Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F" key combination in Windows 10 Pro (Version 1903) do?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

After the recent Windows update, this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> hotkey combination is reserved by Windows, I have even checked in safe mode where no other programs are running. I cannot register this combination in any program I use now. Besides, it's super annoying; I don't understand what it does and how I can change it.

Comment: Must be new, it does not appear on the official keyboard shortcuts list anywhere....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @Moab have you got this Windows version? Is it the same for you?

Comment: I noticed this as well. I previously used this as "Find In Files" in Visual Studio, and now it doesn't work. I used Hotkey Explorer to test it and it says it's registered to an unknown program (presumably a low-level Windows hook) but it doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: Sheesh this is annoying... same with Intellij's `terraform fmt`.

Comment: I have just spent several hours trying to find what new application is hogging this hotkey, but no luck. For me the problem is worse. I use a non-US keyboard and now cannot type the key mapped to AltGr+Shift+F. AltGr, or the right Alt key, is used on international keyboards to type non-ASCII characters. It is effectively the same as Ctrl+Alt, which means that this hidden Ctrl+Alt+Shift+F hotkey prevents typing this character.

Comment: @Barnett Exactly the same.

Comment: I finally solved the issue on my PC, it is indeed related to Windows Pro 10 Version 1903, even if you turn on windows update you won't resolve the issue as windows update seems only download latest "feature only" changes from the latest build but it does not update your windows to the latest version. All you need to do is go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/software-download/windows10 and download "Windows 10 Update Assistant" and then run it so that it will install latest windows version to your PC.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This problem is reported on several support forums for products that use this key
combination. According to all reports this is a problem introduced by the update
to Windows 10 version 1903, when this key is swallowed up by Windows without
doing anything.

It may be undone in a future update, or Microsoft will complete adding the handling
of this new hotkey, but in the meantime here is what I found.

Using Spy++ I saw this funny sequence of events being reported for pressing
these keys:

```
Ctrl down
Shift down
Alt down
F up
Alt up
Ctrl up
Shift up
```

Meaning that the event for "F down" was swallowed up by some component of Windows.
If these three modifier keys are pressed then the result is that the F-key event
is totally nullified.

I then tried [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to intercept this
key sequence, and this worked.
Apparently, AutoHotkey hooks the keyboard at a lower level
than whatever Windows component that swallows up the F-key,
so is able to intercept and handle it first.

For associating this key-sequence with running Explorer, you could use this
AutoHotkey script:

```
!^+F:: Run, explorer.exe
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green `H` icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
If you always want this script to execute, copy it to the user Startup folder at
`C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: I've spent 2 days on it. downloaded almost every software of hotkeys recognition : none.

Comment: I first noticed this after I upgraded Visual Studio and a shortcut I had stopped working. So I logged a report with the VS team: [report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/720782/assigned-shortcut-key-not-working-after-update-to.html) and they referred me to this question :D

Comment: It is still not working even today, it is so annoying, I was so used to CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+F shortcut for formatting codes in VS2019 and now I have to change it to other sequence.